# J2SE and Database Access

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Hi. I am writing a standalone java app, and I want to access a database for persistance, but I couldn't find a good tutorial on what to use, and, the current best/fastest way to do this.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at JDBC Tutorial - [JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is the basic way for accessing the database from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use plain JDBC for connecting to database. More information about JDBC can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)

If you want to go with Object Oriented approach, you can use [EJB3/JPA](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html) or [Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way to for accessing database is JDBC. But for more complex appliactions you can use Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's good idea to use some sort of persistent framework like Hibernate in order to do access database for persistence. This would be much faster and more clean than using plain JDBC and it would be easy to maintain.

this is one simple tutorial,

http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/08/05/first-hibernate-tutorial-%E2%80%93get-hands-on-experience/

http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2009/10/06/hibernate-tutorial-part-ii/